# Join two tables without mixing rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to join 2 tables and for each joined result I need a separate row, but the rows of my query result are somehow mixed:

---

**Schema + Data**:

[image: sql-data]

---

**My Query:**

```
SELECT Table_A.id,

       Table_B.id,

       Table_C.id

FROM   Table_A

LEFT JOIN Table_B
       ON Table_B.id_a = Table_A.id

LEFT JOIN Table_C
       ON Table_C.id_a = Table_A.id
```

---

**The Result:**

[image: actual-result]

**What I want** (3 separate rows - separated by the join-tables' id-column):

[image: desired-result]

**Q:** What am I doing wrong?

=> You could put it in that way: I need all rows of where `id_a` is `1` + `table_a.id=1`. Maybe `JOIN` is the wrong approach here..?

Comment: Joins will not work here, they will merge the rows into one based on the matching criteria. You can use UNION all if you want to append rows after one other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `INNER JOIN UNION` :

```
SELECT A.id A_Id, B.id B_Id, ''c_id
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON B.id_a = A.id

UNION ALL

SELECT A.id A_Id, '' B_Id, c.id c_id
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_C C ON A.id = C.id_a
```

Comment: @Jonathan in that case union will not work and query will become more complex.

Comment: No you already answered the question. I did not see the `''` which fixes the problem! thank you!